# Android animation not working on click

Tags: java, android, animation

My animation I'snt working on click, here is my code:

**Edit:** can now click the button, but nothing happens on click

animation: bottom_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="75%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

here is my java MusicPlayerActivity.java:

```
    btnPlayList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MusicPlayerActivity.this, R.anim.bottom_up);
            ViewGroup hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
            hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
            hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code has a null pointer exception, post your full code

Comment: The hidden panel should not be loaded every time you click for sure.

Answer (score 0):

check if you initialed btnPlayList
like this btnPlayList=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlayList);

or hiddenPanel  not exist in this view that you click on;

Comment: Thank you! I dont know how i missed that... but that was the issue!

Comment: but now when i click the button, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a very common one. It's called NullPointerException because you try to call a method of an object whose reference is null, so the system can't resolve the method. You cand read more about this exception in this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Preventing_NullPointerException).

The line that is probably causing this exception is:

```
ViewGroup hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
```

In order to fix it, I would suggest two things:

- Check that the id `R.id.hidden_panel` is correct.
- If you are contemplating that `R.id.hidden_panel` might not be in your layout, wrap its usage with a null check:

  ```
  if (hiddenPanel != null) {
      hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
      hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
  ```

**EDIT:**

To fix the animation not showing, try calling `startAnimation` after you set the hiddenPanel to Visible, and not before.

Answer (score -1):

java.lang.NullPointerException -> some variables not initialized.
check all variables

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the help, tour and faq before asking and answering questions. Specifically, it's worth reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer before answering. Your answer, while correct, isn't good. It doesn't tell the poster specifically what is wrong or even points him in the right direction.